# testing docker image using python

Tags: python, docker

I have a python code for testing my docker images.

```
import docker
client = docker.from_env()
container = client.containers.run("my_image", ["python  --version"], auto_remove = True)
print("done!")
```

I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/user1/miniconda3/envs/py_test/lib/python3.10/site-packages/docker/api/client.py", line 268, in _raise_for_status
    response.raise_for_status()
  File "/home/user1/miniconda3/envs/py_test/lib/python3.10/site-packages/requests/models.py", line 960, in raise_for_status
    raise HTTPError(http_error_msg, response=self)
requests.exceptions.HTTPError: 400 Client Error: Bad Request for url: http+docker://localhost/v1.41/containers/19b94bfbebc0dbaaf2864b8cc72d1c597fe108a3ddd9bf45b58b8d3c825cb3e6/start

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/user1/tmp_python/test.py", line 5, in <module>
    container = client.containers.run("my_image", ["python  --version"], auto_remove = True)
  File "/home/user1/miniconda3/envs/py_test/lib/python3.10/site-packages/docker/models/containers.py", line 826, in run
    container.start()
  File "/home/user1/miniconda3/envs/py_test/lib/python3.10/site-packages/docker/models/containers.py", line 404, in start
    return self.client.api.start(self.id, **kwargs)
  File "/home/user1/miniconda3/envs/py_test/lib/python3.10/site-packages/docker/utils/decorators.py", line 19, in wrapped
    return f(self, resource_id, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/user1/miniconda3/envs/py_test/lib/python3.10/site-packages/docker/api/container.py", line 1109, in start
    self._raise_for_status(res)
  File "/home/user1/miniconda3/envs/py_test/lib/python3.10/site-packages/docker/api/client.py", line 270, in _raise_for_status
    raise create_api_error_from_http_exception(e)
  File "/home/user1/miniconda3/envs/py_test/lib/python3.10/site-packages/docker/errors.py", line 31, in create_api_error_from_http_exception
    raise cls(e, response=response, explanation=explanation)
docker.errors.APIError: 400 Client Error for http+docker://localhost/v1.41/containers/19b94bfbebc0dbaaf2864b8cc72d1c597fe108a3ddd9bf45b58b8d3c825cb3e6/start: Bad Request ("failed to create shim task: OCI runtime create failed: runc create failed: unable to start container process: exec: "python  --version": executable file not found in $PATH: unknown")
```

however, when I run manually my image, I can get the python version:

```
docker run -it my_image
(base) root@6f9d163cc547:/# python --version
Python 3.9.12
(base) root@6f9d163cc547:/# exit
exit
```

Comment: Is it treating `"python  --version"` as a single command? What happens when you call it with `["python", "--version"]` or `"python --version"` not in a list

Comment: for separated one: error:  exec: "python": executable file not found in $PATH: unknown" 
for the one without list:  error:  exec: "python": executable file not found in $PATH: unknown"

Answer (score 1):

This error:

```
unable to start container process: exec: "python  --version": executable file not found in $PATH: unknown")
```

Means you should be passing a list of arguments:

```
client.containers.run('myimage', ['python', '--version'])
```

Or a single string:

```
client.containers.run('myimage', 'python --version')
```

With your current code, Docker is trying to find an executable file named literally `python --version`. This is exactly what you see with `RUN` and `CMD` statements in a `Dockerfile`: a single string is executed using `/bin/sh -c`, while a list argument is executed directly (e.g., passed as arguments to `execve()`).

This works just fine:

```
import docker
client = docker.from_env()
container = client.containers.run('docker.io/python:3', ['python', '--version'])
print("done!")
```

I find that in my setup, using `auto_remove=True` results in a different error, but that's unrelated to what you show in your question. @KrerkkiatChusap has some suggestions for that issue in their answer.

Comment: Thanks, but still I don't understand how this will solve my error. my_image is an ubuntu image. and I want to see the python version installed on the image

Comment: I am passing  ["python  --version"] this

Comment: `["python --version"]` is the source of the error as larsks mentioned, so using `['python', '--version']` is to fix the error. Once run, larsks code will have the python version output stored in `container` variable (in bytes), so that should solve your problem with obtaining the version of python in the container. Keep in mind that you can easily replace `docker.io/python:3` with the name of your image.

Comment: "I am passing ["python --version"] this" @H'H yes, and as I have tried to explain this answer, that is the source of your problem.

Comment: If you are using one of the base `ubuntu` images, there is no Python installed; you would have to install it yourself.

Answer (score -2):

You code seems to be

```py
container = client.containers.run("my_image", ["python  --version"], auto_remove = True)
container.start()
```

The `docker run` command will create *and start* the container, so there is no need for `container.start()`.

The next problem is then when `auto_remove=True`, the container will be destroyed after it finished the execution, and the library have a hard time obtaining the output from destroyed container. Also, without `detach=True`, the output (byte) will be returned instead of a container object (so calling `.start()` on it will not make sense).

Instead, you can obtain the handle with `detach=True` and manually remove the container after you get the output with `container.logs()`.

```py
import docker
client = docker.from_env()
# The command here is implicitly fixed by larsks' answer.
container = client.containers.run("my_image", ["python", "--version"], detach=True)
output_bytes = container.logs()
# Since the container is already exited, you can skip the `.stop()`.
container.remove()
```